# Reduce a dataframe after group_by with a specific value in a column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following tidyverse problem, formulated as reprex with the mpg dataset below.

For each car model of each manufacturer, I would like to know whether there is a 6-cylinder version available. I can easily produce a column `six.cyl.available` which encodes this property.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- mpg %>% mutate(six.cyl.available = if_else(cyl==6, "yes","no"))
```

<sup>Created on 2018-10-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Now, I  would like to reduce the resulting dataframe by means of `group_by(manufacturer, model)` and
arrive at a dataframe with all columns of the original frame minus "cyl". Instead, I want a column `six.cyl.available`, which contains "yes" if this particular model is available with 6 cyl and "no" if not.  like this:

```r
|manufacturer |model     | displ| year|trans  |drv | cty| hwy|fl |class|six.cyl.available       |
|:------------|:-----------|:----------|---|
|audi         |a4        |   3.1| 2008|auto(av)   |f   |  18|  27|p  |compact    |yes|
|audi         |a4 quattro|   1.8| 1999|manual(m5) |4   |  18|  26|p  |compact    |no|
```

This problem had me stumped for some time now. I am sure there is a simple solution, and I'd be grateful for advice.

Comment: You need only one row per `manufacturer` and `model` right? From which row the values of other columns be selected ?

Comment: one row per manufacturer and model, right. In my original problem, all other fields (apart from cyl) will be equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that you're considering a model to be a unique combination of all the columns in the dataset, since you've included more than just `manufacturer` and `model` columns in your desired output. So you want to group the data frame by everything except `cyl`, then summarize the data based on whether for each combination of attributes, any observations have `cyl` of 6.

You can use `group_by_at(vars(-cyl))` so say that you want to group by all columns *except* `cyl`. After calling `summarise`, `cyl` will be dropped because it isn't included in your grouping. An `ifelse` inside `summarise` lets you setup the yes/no column you want. I'm using `summarise` instead of `mutate` because you're looking for a single row per group.

```r
library(dplyr)

any_six <- ggplot2::mpg %>%
  group_by_at(vars(-cyl)) %>%
  summarise(six.cyl.available = ifelse(any(cyl == 6), "yes", "no"))
print(any_six, width = Inf)
#> # A tibble: 225 x 11
#> # Groups:   manufacturer, model, displ, year, trans, drv, cty, hwy, fl [?]
#>    manufacturer model      displ  year trans      drv     cty   hwy fl   
#>    <chr>        <chr>      <dbl> <int> <chr>      <chr> <int> <int> <chr>
#>  1 audi         a4           1.8  1999 auto(l5)   f        18    29 p    
#>  2 audi         a4           1.8  1999 manual(m5) f        21    29 p    
#>  3 audi         a4           2    2008 auto(av)   f        21    30 p    
#>  4 audi         a4           2    2008 manual(m6) f        20    31 p    
#>  5 audi         a4           2.8  1999 auto(l5)   f        16    26 p    
#>  6 audi         a4           2.8  1999 manual(m5) f        18    26 p    
#>  7 audi         a4           3.1  2008 auto(av)   f        18    27 p    
#>  8 audi         a4 quattro   1.8  1999 auto(l5)   4        16    25 p    
#>  9 audi         a4 quattro   1.8  1999 manual(m5) 4        18    26 p    
#> 10 audi         a4 quattro   2    2008 auto(s6)   4        19    27 p    
#>    class   six.cyl.available
#>    <chr>   <chr>            
#>  1 compact no               
#>  2 compact no               
#>  3 compact no               
#>  4 compact no               
#>  5 compact yes              
#>  6 compact yes              
#>  7 compact yes              
#>  8 compact no               
#>  9 compact no               
#> 10 compact no               
#> # ... with 215 more rows
```

To check that this made sense, I looked at the number of rows of both the original data frame, and the summarized one. There are very few observations that have all the same attributes, so the number of rows of the summarized data frame is only a few less than the original.

```r
nrow(ggplot2::mpg)
#> [1] 234
nrow(any_six)
#> [1] 225
```

<sup>Created on 2018-10-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Two worthwile enhancements to my repertoire - I didn't knwo the 'any' variant, and I wasn't aware that group_by(-cyl) would work.

Comment: You can do that with group_by_at, not group_by

Answer (score 1):

If all other columns per group would have the same value we could give "yes" value if `any` of the `cyl` column has 6 then we return "yes" for that group else give "no" and then `slice` any one row from the group (here I have taken 1st row) and remove the `cyl` column from the output.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
   group_by(manufacturer, model) %>%
   mutate(six.cyl.available = if (any(cyl==6)) "yes" else "no") %>%
   slice(1) %>%
   select(-cyl)
```

Comment: This answer solves my problem perfectly, thank you very much! The 'any' did the trick, thank you very much for enhancing my repertoire!However, I accepted camilles reply as answer, because it is slightly more general, with the group_by(-cyl) and may hence help more people.